# Why don't we use simple binary values to compress data

Tags: algorithm, encoding, huffman-code, compression

In Huffman algorithm we form a tree and than replace each character with the tree value of 1 and 0, why don't we simply use the binary digits like `a=0,b=1,c=10,d=01,e=11` and so on than replace them with the characters and when decompressing apply the reverse and replace the binary digits with the alphabets.

**Like this:**

```
character Huffman-code binary-code
a            00            0
b            01            1
c            101           01
```

and so on...

Comment: The point of Huffman is that the result is unambiguous. Using your example, if the code you want to decompress is "00101" then it's unambiguously "ac" in Huffman. Using your algorithm it could be "aabab", "acc", "acab"...

Comment: Huffman code for "abcd" is "000110111110"  there is a chance of ambiguity as well isn't it?

Comment: No, and by the way that's not a Huffman code since it's not optimal (the only code that starts with a 1 is 101, which could therefore just be 1). It's still a prefix code, so it's unambiguously decodable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important condition for the Huffman codes is that no two are a prefix of each other. If you just renumber them (as I think this is what your suggestion is) you lose this property.

To see why this breaks, look at "01" as the output. In the non-Huffman version it might either be "0" followed by "1" (thus "ab"), or "01" (thus "c"), you can't tell which.